# Application crashes after VS2012 install

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm not quite sure where to go with the initially...

I've got an application that has been built in VS2010, using both MFC and .NET 2.0. I then installed VS2012. Before even launching VS2012 I've tried running the application again and it now crashes just after startup with an "Application has stopped working" error.

It does however work, if I launch the application via an F5 in VS2010 (i.e. Debugger attatched right from the start).

Does anyone have any suggestions on what possible causes/fixes there may be for this? I'm currently not sure what to look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately it was completely unrelated to VS2012 - doh. Had an old executable that was being run, and a number of dependencies were missing.

Answer (score 0):

You probably never installed the redistributable packages for the VS2010 runtimes. Use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) or similar tools to find out what DLL is missing, figure out where it comes from, and install that runtime package.